# Custom stepping tree traversal generator

Tags: javascript, typescript, iterator, generator

I want to traverse a dom tree with a generator with a custom matcher callback, when yield value, return an array with traversed nodes in between. Say I have this structure.

```
  root
  / \
P1   P2
 |   |
T1   T2
```

I want to do `iter.next(isP)` or `iter.next(isText)` update matcher and step til next node match.

```
type Matcher = (node: INode) => boolean
export function* nextNode(node: INode, matcher: Matcher = () => true, store: []): Generator<INode, any, Matcher> {
  let reset: Matcher = matcher
  store = store.concat(node)
  if (reset(node)) {
    reset = yield store
    store = []
  }
  if (node.children) {
    for (let childNode of node.children) {
      yield *nextNode(childNode, matcher, store)
    }
  }
  return
}
```

The problem with my code is `reset` is lost when function call stack is popped. For example if I'm in T1 and previous stack is `isText`, now if I do `iter.next(isP)` won't work. How do I do it?

```
const iter = nextNode(root, isT)
iter.next() <-- this is T1
iter.next(isP) <-- this is T2 should be P2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the return value of the generator to pass through the traversal state. When the `yield*` returns from the first child of root, it will need to give you the store and matcher that became available in the `next` call after root and p1 were yielded.

```
…
if (node.children) {
  for (let childNode of node.children) {
    [reset, store] = yield* nextNode(childNode, reset, store)
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                           ^^^^^
  }
}
return [reset, store]
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

A complete example:

```js
function* nextNode(node, matcher = () => true, store = []) {
  store.push(node.name)
  if (matcher(node)) {
    matcher = yield store
    store = []
  }
  if (node.children) {
    for (let childNode of node.children) {
      [matcher, store] = yield* nextNode(childNode, matcher, store)
    }
  }
  return [matcher, store]
}

const node = (name, children) => ({name, children})
const is = c => n => n.name[0] == c

const iter = nextNode(node("root", [
  node("p1", [node("t1")]),
  node("p2", [node("t2")])
]), is("t"))
console.log("until next t:", iter.next())
console.log("until next p:", iter.next(is("p")))
console.log("until next p:", iter.next(is("p")))
```

Comment: I tried it but doesn't seem working, can you show me the full code? I'm okey without the store just yield node.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation here! I do realize an issue with it is that the return and yield type is not consistent, so if I give a false matcher it'll return `[matcher, nodes]` instead of nodes, and given we have to return matcher to the outer scope, I don't really want to return matcher to the caller.

Comment: @Mengo I was assuming that you didn't care about the generator's return type, and that the last segment of the tree should not be yielded if the last node is not matched. Your solution with the closure might be easier though.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, seems an easy solution is to just have a global matcher.

```
type Matcher = (node: INode) => boolean
type TYield = INode[]
function* nextNode(
  node: INode,
  matcher: Matcher = () => true,
): Generator<TYield, TYield, Matcher> {
  let store: INode[] = []
  let reset = matcher
  function* _nextNode(node: INode): Generator<TYield, any, Matcher> {
    store.push(node)
    if (reset(node)) {
      reset = yield store
      if (!reset) reset = matcher
      store = []
    }
    if (node.children) {
      for (const childNode of node.children) {
        yield* _nextNode(childNode)
      }
    }
    return
  }
  yield* _nextNode(node)
  return store
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend to do `if (store.length) yield store;` instead of `return store`, changing the type to `Generator<Inode[], void, Matcher>`. Makes it easier to use with standard iteration?

Comment: Good advice! I'm trying to verify how it behave, but get this error from TS, `Cannot iterate value because the 'next' method of its iterator expects type 'Matcher', but for-of will always send 'undefined'`, I think in plain JS it should be fine since matcher has a default value, do you know how to pass argument with for..of?

Comment: Ah, I think it needs to be `Generator<Inode[], void, Matcher?>` (or ``Matcher | undefined``)